# Pulling text from a .txt file to insert into a batch file to run an exe

Tags: windows, batch-file

Im very new to this and would love some help.

Im trying to run a program in command line but i need to add a drive letter that changes and a part number that also changes. 
example: 
    `start "" "U:\ISO\fileTool\file_Update.exe /m:(PARTNUMBER) /t:(DRIVELETTER) /v /l:logfile.text"`

The program uses what is after m: for the part number I need.
It also uses what comes after T: for the drive letter I want to copy to.
I want to be able to choose if the v (validate) is inserted.
I want to choose if the l (logfile) is inserted.

As part of the prep I have a batch file to ask the user for the part number, drive letter, if they want to validate and if they want a log file. The output of that is a text file that looks like this without the information in the brackets

text file output:

```
Variable One   = 1234 (partnumber)

Variable Two   = D (Driveletter)

Variable Three = Y (validate could be N to exclude)

Variable Four  = Y  (logfile could be N to exclude)
```

So what i need is a way to have the variable information inserted into the batch file and run the .exe file with the switches
EX:
    `start "" "U:\ISO\fileTool\file_Update.exe /m:12345 /t:m /v /l:logfile.txt"`

Comment: Don't write it too a text file.  Just use their answers as is and build the line you need to execute using the `IF` command based on their answers.

Comment: could you provide an example? I have this for the bat file"@echo off
del USBsettings.txt
set Output="%USERPROFILE%\desktop"

set /p VarOne=Enter Part Number: 
set /p VarTwo=Enter Drive Letter: 
set /p VarThree=Enter Validate? Y/N: 
set /p VarFour=Enter Log File? Y/N: 

REM enter your desired output here
echo Variable One   = %VarOne% >> %Output%\USBsettings.txt
echo Variable Two   = %VarTwo% >> %Output%\USBsettings.txt
echo Variable Three = %VarThree% >> %Output%\USBsettings.txt
echo Variable Four  = %VarFour% >> %Output%\USBsettings.txt

echo.
echo File has been placed %Output%
exit"

Comment: and the last line would be "start "" "U:\ISO\ModularUSBTool\USBRecoveryCreator_SecurityUpdate.exe /m: /v"

Comment: Do not put that much code in a comment!  Edit your question and put the batch code in there!

Comment: You should not put the entire command line `U:\ISO\fileTool\file_Update.exe /m:12345 /t:m /v /l:logfile.txt` in between `""` because all this is treated as the program path/name; you should write it like this: `start "" "U:\ISO\fileTool\file_Update.exe" /m:12345 /t:m /v /l:logfile.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Squashman already noted in his comment, you don't need a file:

```
@echo off 
set /p "VarOne=Enter Part Number:     " 
set /p "VarTwo=Enter Drive Letter:    " 
set /p "VarThree=Enter Validate? Y/N: "
if /i "%VarThree%"=="Y" (set "VarThree=/v") else (set "VarThree=")
set /p "VarFour=Use Log File? Y/N:    "
if /i "%VarFour%"=="Y" (set "VarFour=/l:logfile.txt") else (set "VarFour=")
start "" "U:\ISO\fileTool\file_Update.exe" /m:%VarOne% /t:%VarTwo% %VarThree% %VarFour%
```

Comment: this worked perfectly for what i needed, thank you for your help. I see where I was going wrong and this IS a much better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

CALL :run %*

:loop
SET "input="
SET /p "input=Part[,Drive[,Verify[,Logfile]]]"

IF DEFINED input CALL :run %input%&GOTO loop

GOTO :EOF 


:run
FOR %%a IN (logfile verifyp) DO SET "%%a="
IF "%~4" neq "" SET "logfile=/l:%~4"
IF /i "%~3" equ "Y" SET "verifyp=/v"
IF /i "%~2" equ "" (SET "drive=D") ELSE (SET "drive=%~2")
ECHO(start "" "U:\ISO\fileTool\file_Update.exe /m:%~1 /t:%drive% %verifyp% %logfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

This would allow you to run as *thisbatch* 1234 d y mylogfilename

or simply as *thisbatch* 1234

to default to drive `D` with no verify and no logfile.

I misread that you wanted `y` to specify logfile = logfile.txt

```
IF /i "%~4" equ "y" SET "logfile=/l:logfile.txt"
```

in plac of the "~4" processing in the `run` subroutine should convert that to "use `logfile.txt` if last parameter is y"

Comment: this also worked... and if  i was going to keep the txt file i would have used this method. thank you.